# Сохранение данных банковской/кредитной карты, как в приложении AliExpress /Yota /сбербанк_онлайн

Tags: android, алгоритм

Суть такая: в приложении AliExpress есть возможность добавить данные банковской карточки и дальше с него автоматически производить оплату.

Каким образом реализуется сам алгоритм?

Каким образом мы можем сохранить данные карты в приложении, или это не в приложении сохраняется, а отправляется на сервер?

Если отправляется на сервер, то наверное, с шифрованием? То есть сам алгоритм работы при вот таком действии, с кодом сам уже попробую реализовать.

Приложении AliExpress взял, как пример, так как с этим в нём и сталкивался

Comment: хранить данные карты на сайте плохая практика. хранится обычно только маска карты, а при помощи банка в дальнейшем идет списание по авторизованной карте.

Comment: Я бы возложил хранение карты на платежную систему. во многих есть такая возможность.

Comment: @eri, значит мне нужно подключать библиотеку платёжной системы? Они при этом хотят большие проценты от суммы

Comment: Почитайте про [PCI DSS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_DSS).

Comment: @zayn1991 а бывает экваринг без процентов?

Comment: Только за использование шифрования при передаче? Хорошо сидят, с такими процентами

Comment: "PCI DSS определяет следующие шесть областей контроля и 12 основных требований по безопасности." - за реализацию этих требований, поддержание инфраструктуры и регулярное прохождение аудитов они и берут свой процент.

Comment: @Aleksey, получается, если клиент потеряет деньги, он будет судиться не с нами, а с PCI DSS?

Comment: @zayn1991, вы хотите самостоятельно реализовать обработку и хранение карточных данных, не имея ни малейших представлений ни о технической ни о юридической стороне вопроса?
В любом случае, простейшим вариантом не нарушающим закон, в вашем случае, мне кажется интеграция с существующей платёжной системой.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Хранить данные банковских карт в приложении Вы не имеете права по закону. Хранить эти данные на сервере Вы можете если имеете сертификат PCI DSS ([для начала ссылка в википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_DSS)), получить который очень не просто и стоит это не малых денег. Единственный, простой, вариант - это использовать платежный системы к примеру [Яндекс.Касса](https://tech.yandex.ru/money/doc/dg/concepts/kassa-integration-docpage/?_openstat=promo;adwords;newsemant&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=kassa_search_newsemant&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=189648707039,%2B%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%20%2B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0&utm_term=%2B%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%20%2B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0&gclid=CjwKEAjwoLfHBRD_jLW93remyAQSJABIygGpWpLeNBYEvPGwmMzKmwQB6wj5Rf3r8hJIaGpg09pyEhoCSGjw_wcB) и тому подобные ([ссылка на рейтинг](http://tagline.ru/payment-systems-rating/)). Большинство этих систем поддерживает рекуррентные платежи, т.е. данные карты хранит сама система и дальнейшие платежи (к примеру по подписке), делает автоматически по вашему запросу, без дополнительных действий со стороны пользователя.

Comment: Нет, не единственный. При малом числе (до 20 000) транзакций сертифицироваться по PCI DSS может быть не так уж сложно, т. к. все обязательные проверки делегируются банку-эквайеру.

Comment: @D-side что-то вы путаете, почитайте [3. Для кого требования стандарта PCI DSS являются обязательными?](http://www.pcidss.ru/faq/)

Comment: Ничего я не путаю. Вы другие пункты посмотрите, например 13. Процедура сертификации по PCI DSS варьируется в зависимости от числа обрабатываемых транзакций за единицу времени. И при малом числе транзакций процедура не катастрофически сложная/затратная и кроме самоконтроля зависит только от банка-эквайера.

Comment: @D-side понятия "сложная/затратная" для всех разные. Не понимаю, к чему все ваши комментарии? Ответ на вопрос дан, даны ссылки, топикастер сам примет решение проходить сертификацию или воспользоваться платежной системой. В 99% случаев, проще и дешевле - платежная система, если вы конечно не владелец AliExpress.

Comment: К тому, что по вашему ответу похоже, будто бы PCI DSS это нечто совершенно непроходимое, кроме как для настоящих гигантов. А это не так.

Comment: @D-side я не говорил, что это непроходимо, я сказал, что это сложно и затратно, мало того, каждый год нужно проходить повторные тесты для подтверждения сертификата. И да - это сложно и затратно в 99% случаев.

Comment: И тем не менее, это выполнимо и может иметь смысл. "Единственный простой" – это да, ок. После правки стало лучше. Минус убрал.

Comment: а можно ссылку на закон о запрете хранения данных банковских карт в приложении?

Comment: @Murad я не юрист, но могу сказать, что обработка данных платежных карт относится к банковской деятельности, и регулируется в России законом о банках и банковской деятельности `подсказали коллеги из юротдела`

Comment: Можно ли хранить на сервере только номера банковских карт?

Answer (score 3):

За хранение карточек без прохождение PCI DSS с вами совершат действия сексуального-насильственного характера.

Пока я видел 2 метода - оба хранят данные в компании эквайринге. (aliexpress использует эквайринг alipay):

1. Виртуальные счета - вы создаете виртуального пользователя в платежной системе. Связываете его со своим аккаунтом и выставляете ему счета. Например так делает monetka.ru (она же payanyway ). Пример документации https://payanyway.ru/info/p/ru/public/merchants/SDKphp.pdf стр 16 "Создание нового пользователя"
2. Хранение виртуальных карт - по сути то же самое. Встречал у альфабанка. Но вы видите конкретную карту, часть информации скрыта. Пользователь через сервис привязывает карточку, вы видите "виртульную" карту или список карт и привязываете к его аккаунту. Потом при оплате даете ему выбор карты и подтверждение оплаты.

Это называется подписки, рекурентные платежи или регулярные платежи. Можете пройти по платежным система и посмотреть как у них реализовано.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю кейса с отправкой инфы о карте на сервер - это как-то совсем не секьюрно и получается какой-то сбор карт.

**Все строго шифровать!**

Тут либо карту шифровать по пину/паролю - очень хорошая [статья](https://nelenkov.blogspot.ru/2012/04/using-password-based-encryption-on.html?view=classic) по этой теме.

Либо использовать `SQLCipher` - читать [тут](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/).

И будьте предельно внимательны и ответственны при разработке хранения этих важных данных.

Comment: мне бы алгоритм общий знать

Answer (score 2):

Хранить такие данные на телефоне **небезопасно**.
Если все таки есть желание хранить, то можно использовать 3D шифрование(TripleDES)

Вот пример:

```
 public class TripleDESHelper {
private Context mContext;

public TripleDESHelper(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

public String encrypt(String message) throws Exception {
    final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
    final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("H3423G583424232CR9"
            .getBytes("utf-8"));
    final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
    for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8; ) {
        keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
    }

    final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, getString(mContext.getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID));
    final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

    final byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
    final byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);

    return Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}

public String decrypt(String message) throws Exception {

    final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
    final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("H3423G583424232CR9"
            .getBytes("utf-8"));
    final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
    for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8; ) {
        keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
    }

    final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, getString(mContext.getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID));
    final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
    final Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

    final byte[] encData = Base64.decode(message, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(encData);
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),new String(plainText, "UTF-8"));
    return new String(plainText, "UTF-8");

}
}
```

Лучше всего передавать данные на сервер по  HTTPS и при этом еще и шифровать алгоритмом 4-х рукопожатий. Асимметричные алгоритмы (RSA, El-Gamal)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы действовал так:

1. По https на сервер бы отправлял все данные карты(номер, срок действия, CVC).
2. На сервере использовал бы [Stripe](https://stripe.com/), чтобы привязять карту к конкретному юзеру. Stripe сам берет на себя вс нагрузку по защищенному хранению и использованию карты.
3. На сервере бы хранил только идентификаторы карт, которые сформировал Stripe.
4. Локально бы хранил только мета информацию(последние 4 цыфры и тд.)